# Unable to access Clipboard Content from foreground service in Android 10+

Tags: android, service, floating

I know that we can't access clipboard content from background services in 10+ but there is an application that shows copied text on a floating widget in Android 10+ devices using foreground service [here's that app](https://youtu.be/MaYmxt1qDHI). I want to achieve that functionality somehow! please help me.

My app is working fine in android P and lower devices!

**FloatingViewService.java**

```
public class FloatingViewService extends Service implements View.OnClickListener {

private WindowManager wm;
private View floatv;
View collapsed;
View expanded;
CharSequence copiedText;
EditText editText;

public FloatingViewService(){

}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();


    // getting the widget layout from xml using layout inflater
    floatv  = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.layout_floating_widget,null);


    // setting window manager layout parameters
    // set foucus able ,, wrap content, set on lock screen etc...
    final WindowManager.LayoutParams wrules = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
    );


    // getting window service and adding floating view to it
    wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    wm.addView(floatv,wrules);



    //adding click listener to close button and expanded view
    collapsed =  floatv.findViewById(R.id.layoutCollapsed);
    expanded =  floatv.findViewById(R.id.layoutExpanded);
    editText = floatv.findViewById(R.id.pastehere);





    // adding an touch listener to make drag movement of the floating view
    floatv.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayoutParent).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        private int initialX;
        private int initialY;
        private float touchX;
        private float touchY;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
               switch (event.getAction()){
                   case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        initialX = wrules.x;
                        initialY = wrules.y;
                        touchX = event.getRawX();
                        touchY = event.getRawY();
                        return true;

                     /*as we implemented OnTouchListener() to the root view, OnClickListner() won’t work. So, to detect clicks we will detect clicks in MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE in the OnTouchListener() using below code:*/
                   case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                      int diffX = (int) (event.getRawX() - touchX);
                      int diffY = (int)  (event.getRawY() - touchY);

                      if(diffX < 10 && diffY < 10){

                          if (isViewCollapsed()){
                              collapsed.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                              expanded.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                              wrules.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND;
                              wm.updateViewLayout(floatv,wrules);
                          }else {
                              collapsed.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                              expanded.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                              wrules.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE;
                              wm.updateViewLayout(floatv,wrules);
                          }

                      }



                       return true;

                   case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                       // moving the widget across the screen
                       wrules.x = initialX + (int) (event.getRawX() - touchX);
                       wrules.y = initialY +  (int) (event.getRawY() - touchY);
                       wm.updateViewLayout(floatv,wrules);


                       return true;


               }

            return false;
        }
    });


    ClipboardManager clipboardManager = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);

    clipboardManager.addPrimaryClipChangedListener(new ClipboardManager.OnPrimaryClipChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrimaryClipChanged() {
            copiedText = clipboardManager.getPrimaryClip().getItemAt(0).getText();

            if(copiedText != null){
                editText.setText(String.valueOf(copiedText));
                wm.updateViewLayout(floatv,wrules);
            }
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), copiedText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(floatv != null) wm.removeView(floatv);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
      if(v.getId() == R.id.layoutExpanded){
          collapsed.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          expanded.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      }else if(v.getId() == R.id.buttonClose){
          stopSelf();
    }
}

private boolean isViewCollapsed() {
    return floatv == null || floatv.findViewById(R.id.layoutCollapsed).getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE;
}
```

}

**layout_floating_widget.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutParent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <!-- this is the collapsed layout -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutCollapsed"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/collapsed_iv"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_menu_book_24" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/buttonClose"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_close_24"
                android:background="@color/teal_200"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <!-- this is the expanded layout -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutExpanded"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#a0c3d7"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/buttonSimplifiedCodingExpanded"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_markunread_24"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/buttonSimplifiedCoding"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                    android:paddingRight="15dp"
                    android:paddingTop="15dp"
                    android:text="Dictionary"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/pastehere"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

[see these images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIfk7.png)

[text should appear in editText, working in android 9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9pZF.png)

Comment: In that app, the functionality demonstrated in the video does not appear to be available on newer versions. From what I can gather, it's called "Live Translation", and it's simply removed from the options in versions that don't support it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5mgQ.png. The left is Android 8, the right is 11.

Comment: I have an android 10 phone and tested this application thoroughly, It is working as expected. As soon as I copy text from somewhere and click on floating widget it is displayed. Instead of the "Live Translation", there is "Popup window" option in the navigation drawer.

Comment: Here's that application link that I have installed on my phone https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.grandsons.dictboxur

Comment: That's not what that video shows, though. It shows the window popping up from the context menu Copy item. It doesn't show the floating widget at all, so your question is unclear, at best. Which part are you having trouble with, exactly? There doesn't seem to be anything unexpected happening there. When the floating widget is clicked, it starts a floating `Activity` which can read the clipboard 'cause it'll be in the foreground.

Comment: Actually, in reviewing the restrictions, it says "the app that currently has focus", so you possibly could do it with a `View` directly in `WindowManager`, too, though I've not tested that. In any case, the floating widget approach isn't really affected by the restriction because it doesn't require the clipboard listener.

Comment: Actually, I have created Dictionary app, having Live serach feature. Whenever a user clicks on "Live Search" floating widget is appeared. And when user copy text and click on floating widget, its corresponding meaning is get displayed. It was working fine untill android 9. But it's not working in 10+. The same features is working in play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.grandsons.dictboxur

Comment: If you would like some assistance with your app, you'll need to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue. As I mentioned above, there's nothing terribly complicated happening; it's just reading the clipboard when it comes to the foreground and gets focus. We can't know which part isn't working in your setup, however, without seeing it.

Comment: Please, check out the codes

Comment: Your `OnPrimaryClipChangedListener` is not going to work anymore on those newer versions. That's what you need to change for Q+. On those versions, the Dict Box app requires that the user click the floating widget to show its popup window, which can then read from the clipboard since it's got focus. Yours looks like you only have the popup window part, so you need to decide where and how you want the user to click to trigger an update there, because you can't just listen for a clipboard change anymore.

Comment: I think you didn't see above pictures clearly, i have floating widget upon user click it displays popup window.

Comment: How can i get popup window foucus so that i get clipboard's data

Comment: You have only one `View` added to the `WindowManager`. You don't have two separate `View`s for the widget and the window. That's what I meant. That's irrelevant, though, because the `OnPrimaryClipChangedListener` is the issue. That's not going to run anymore, so you need to move the stuff that's currently in `onPrimaryClipChanged()` to a separate method that can be called both from `onPrimaryClipChanged()`, and also from where you handle the click.

Comment: You're right. I did misspeak in that comment. I think I meant to say "…so you need to decide how you want to adjust your code to trigger the update from the click, too".

Comment: Can you give code example, please?

Comment: My test setup is quite different than yours, and is in Kotlin, so it probably won't help. In yours, simply move everything in `onPrimaryClipChanged()` into another method; for example, `private void update()`. Then call `update()` from `onPrimaryClipChanged()`, and also from where you handle the click to expand. I assume that's in the `onClick()` method, but that's not called anywhere, nor is `setOnClickListener()` called on any of your `View`s, so I'm not sure what you actually have running.

Comment: Looks like you might have to change the `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE`, as you may have expected from the quoted restriction. I used `FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL` and it seems to work nicely. Here's my quick test, in case it might help: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DQaEs0lHTAv6siCFvyKi-40qYmv2t--2/view?usp=sharing. You can probably figure it out, even if you've not seen Kotlin before. The syntax is a little different, but the core stuff is all the same.

Comment: In the **layout_floating_widget.xml** file, I have created two views: one for a collapsed widget that will be moved across the screen and another for showing Meaning to the user. Meaning View was set as hidden, it is only going to be displayed if the user touch i.e.  X and Y diff is less than 10 with the following code `if(diffX < 10 && diffY < 10){ // display expanded else collapsed view}`

Comment: Ah, yeah, I see the repeated code there now. Yeah, you'd want to `update()` when expanding.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help,  adding `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL` flag in windowManager works in my android 10. Thanks a lot!